# Explain override in BDH function in Bloomberg

Tags: excel, bloomberg

I have quite complicated BDH function with many overrides, could you recommend any books or Website that I can find Information about these overrides ?

```
=BDH($B$9,"TRADE",$C$1,$C$2,"Dir=V","Dts=S","Sort=A","IntrRw=True","CondCodes=H","QRM=H","ExchCode=S","BrkrCodes=S","RPSCodes=H","RPTParty=H","RPTContra=H","RPTRemuneration=H","RPTAtsIndicator=H","BICMICCodes=S","Type=S","Price=S","Size=S","TradeTime=S","Yield=H","ActionCodes=H","IndicatorCodes=H","UpfrontPrice=H","Spread=H","UseDPDF=Y","cols=10;rows=757")
```

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.

Comment: What do you mean "with many overrides"? What is the `BDH` code, what have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Details of override options are available in the Bloomberg terminal, use `FLDS<GO>` for details.

Also, the API Developer Guide has a section on converting Bloomberg Excel formulas to their API equivalent: 
[Bloomberg Core API Developer Guide](https://data.bloomberglp.com/professional/sites/10/2017/03/BLPAPI-Core-Developer-Guide.pdf)

Page 95 describes intra-day tick requests (i.e. the BDH "TRADE" function in your example).

Answer (score 0):

It's all explained in the help for the function.

In Excel, select the cell with the function, click on the arrow next to the "AutoSum" button and select "More Functions...".

[image]

Then click on the "Help on this function" link at the bottom of the window that pops up.